Detecting and casting Linq expressions accordingly
I wrote an extension method to make it easier to add multi-column indexes in EF 8 (.NET 8) as follows:
public static IndexBuilder<TEntityType> HasIndexUnique<TEntityType>
(
    this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntityType> builder,
    string indexName,
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntityType, object?>>> includeExpressions
) where TEntityType : class
{
    if ((includeExpressions is null) || (!includeExpressions.Any()))
    {
        var currentMethod = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
        throw (new Exception($@"The method [{currentMethod?.DeclaringType?.FullName}.{currentMethod?.Name}] was called without any [{nameof(includeExpressions)}]."));
    }

    var propertyNames = includeExpressions
        .Select
        (
            e =>
            // Casting issue depending on what was sent in.
            ((MemberExpression) ((UnaryExpression) e.Body).Operand).Member.Name
        )
        .ToArray();

    var indexBuilder = builder
        .HasIndex
        (
            propertyNames,
            $@"{indexName}"
        )
        .IsUnique(unique: true);

    return (indexBuilder);
}

The built-in overloads of the EntityTypeBuilder<TEntityType>.HasIndex are string based (which I think is clunky). The overloads that support an Expression syntax only allow one column. The above method works like a charm and makes the calling code much easier to read.
builder
    .HasIndexUnique
    (
        "Index_IndexName_Unique",
        e => e.ModelId,
        e => e.ModelEntityPrincipleId,
        e => e.ModelEntityDependentId,
        e => e.ModelEntityBridgeId
    );

In the example above, all properties passed in are of type Int64. When I try to send in a String property, the expression cast fails.
builder.HasIndexUnique("Index_IndexName_Unique", e => e.Name);

// Exception at this line:
((MemberExpression) ((UnaryExpression) e.Body).Operand).Member.Name
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression'.'

How can I detect and handle properties of different types in order to cast them correctly? I already anticipate a few data types as follows and that should suffice:
Int64, String, DateTime, Object, Byte []

I would appreciate a solution, but would also like to understand what makes an expression Unary or Property or other types that I have not explored.
EDIT:
public partial class ModelEntityRelationship:
    IEntity<ModelEntityRelationship>
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual long ModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }

    public virtual long ModelEntityPrincipleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ModelEntity ModelEntityPrinciple { get; set; } = new();

    public virtual long ModelEntityDependentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ModelEntity ModelEntityDependent { get; set; } = new();

    public virtual long? ModelEntityBridgeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ModelEntity? ModelEntityBridge { get; set; }
}

I am including the source Entity class to clarify my source of confusion. All property declarations are identical except their data types. So why would the expression type change from Unary to Property when sending in Int64 and String objects respectively?

Why not? Compiler decided to do not cast reference type to object, but value types needs boxing. Wirite helper function UnwrapConvert and use when needed.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv: I do not know enough about Linq Expressions, hence the question. What would such a function look for and look like?

Why are you trying to define complex indexes in the application code? You will have to change them in production sooner or later, due to changing data and queries. The EF model isn't a model of the database. Index column matters too, and this index will only help when trying to load an entire Model from the top. It won't help if you use ModelEntity.Model. It won't help accelerate referential integrity checks for the various FKs either. Most likely you need the 4 individual indexes, not 1 4-way index

As for (which I think is clunky) consider what you're trying to do now. You're trying to find out the mapped column names, which are either the property names or hard-coded strings in Column attributes or HasColumnName calls, defined right next to HasIndex. The table columns don't change when you rename property names, so using expressions isn't as helpful as you think.

PS 1) EF already created indexes for FKs by convention 2) the mapped column name information may not be available when you call HasIndex anyway. Nothing requires HasIndex to be called before HasColumn. The full model is constructed after OnModelCreating completes and is available through DbContext.Model. The attempted code can only work for attribute-mapped columns.

Another possibility is to actually create indexes for the configured FKs instead of trying to pass expressions. EntityTypeBuilder.Metadata has AddIndex overloads that accept a list of IMutablePropertys. I don't see how you can get all the properties, but GetForeingKeys() gives indirect access to IMutableForeignKey.Properties

The question is based on an assumption that's not true: The built-in overloads of the EntityTypeBuilder.HasIndex are string based. There are overloads that accept lambda expressions. Also, using the name includeExpressions is confusing, because included columns in an index have a different meaning.

@GertArnold: I did mention the expression overload in my question. I know it exists. I just did not know that you could use an anonymous type to specify multiple indexes (as Panagiotis Kanavos pointed out). As for the parameter name, I just lifted it off EF's own HasIndex method.

I would suggest to create extension method which removes not needed convert, which is added by casting to object value types.
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    [return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(ex))]
    public static Expression? UnwrapConvert(this Expression? ex)
    {
        if (ex == null)
            return null;

        switch (ex.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked :
            case ExpressionType.Convert        :
            {
                var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)ex;
                if (unaryExpression.Method == null)
                    return unaryExpression.Operand.UnwrapConvert();
                break;
            }
        }

        return ex;
    }
}

So in your case you can simple cast to MemberExpression
((MemberExpression)e.Body.UnwrapConvert()).Member.Name


The OP has a bigger problem than they realize - they need the mapped column names, not the property names, to construct the index. That means accessing DbContext.Model and going from there to IEntityType, IProperty and then one of the GetColumnName overloads. EntityTypeBuilder has a Metadata which in turn has an AddIndex(IReadOnlyList<IMutableProperty>) method, but where can one find the properties?

@PanagiotisKanavos, agree, function do not care about real column names.

Wait: .HasIndex(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName }); is available

Sure, I know about this. Question was: why Lambda body is UnaryExpression for value types and for string is not. Anyway, if we understand, why OP created this function, maybe we can find better solution.

I'm not saying you don't know it. I'm asking why is there a question when what the OP wants already exists. There's no reason to juggle expressions when the feature is there since EF Core 1

@PanagiotisKanavos, I did not know you could do that, thanks. My overall scenario is quite different, so I do not care about column names, only properties.

@RaheelKhan what is the scenario? EF already indexes the FKs.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv: Thanks! That helps me understand the expression object model a little better. It is also now clearer that the difference between value and reference types (boxing) was causing the two scenarios.

@PanagiotisKanavos: I could not possibly explain the scenario as a comment. It is too involved. If you are curious, I would be happy to explain. If SO allows you to open a direct conversation, I would welcome it.

You can explain that in the question and yes, you do care about column names because only these go into CREATE INDEX. Besides, the fact FK indexes are created using a convention suggests the best place to do what you want is a custom convention that replaces ForeignKeyIndexConvention. At this point you have all the info. Looking at the code it seems you only need to overload CreateIndex and its callers to create one index with all FKs instead of one per FK
